# MySQL: update by selection condition

Tags: mysql

I have system of questions and answers,
each question should have 4 answers

I need to run SQL query to update question's "class" to be "D" (to prevent it from appear) if it has less than 4 answers

tables structures:

question (table)

```
id     text     class
1      Is..      A
2      Where..   B
3      where..   A
4      Why..     A 
5      Do..      A
```

answer (table)

```
id     qid     text
1       1       ..
2       1       ..
3       1       ..
4       2       ..
5       3       ..
```

note: "answer.qid" refer to "question.id"

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something with subquery like:

```
UPDATE question
SET class = 'D'
WHERE id IN 
         (SELECT qid
          FROM answer
          GROUP BY qid
          HAVING count(qid) < 4)
```

Comment: pls how to count questions (have less than 4 answers)?

Comment: Sorry dear almas, but have you seen the answers before posting your answer?

Comment: `SELECT qid, count(qid)
          FROM answer
          GROUP BY qid
          HAVING count(qid) < 4`

Comment: @FarhangAmary There is a difference if you read it word by word. You still have a typo as well. question != questions.

Comment: @almasshaikh thanks for notifying, but I think only a type is not a good reason for same answer, any way, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

On the fly I would say, you could use a **subselect**:

```
UPDATE question SET class='D' WHERE ( SELECT count(*) FROM answer INNER JOIN answer.qid = question.id ) < 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update question
 set class='D'
 where question.id in (select qid from answer group by qid having count(*)<4)
```

Comment: fix typo select qid from answer group by qid having count(*)<4

Comment: immediately after posting the answer I see it, but there was an error while updating it, finally I fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Typo `update question
 set class='D'
 where questions.id` should be `update question
 set class='D'
 where question.id`